# All google sites/apps will run faster in Google Chrome than any other browser. Is it true?

Tags: windows-7, firefox, google-chrome

All google sites/apps will run faster in Google Chrome than any other browser. Is it true?

Comment: if you really want to see the difference between browsers, try some Javscript heavy sites, for instance http://www.chromeexperiments.com/

Answer (score 1):

The benchmark they are referencing is this one:

http://v8.googlecode.com/svn/data/benchmarks/v5/run.html

(Bigger score = faster)

Try running that on different browsers - the difference is most noticeable when changing from Internet Explorer to Chrome.

On my Mac, Chrome 6 gets 3500, Opera 10.53 gets 1760 and Firefox 3.6.4 gets 170. My iPad gets 82.

So the answer (using the benchmark that Google wrote and are using to tune their javascript engine) is yes. Chrome runs javascript the fastest, so Google's javascript heavy apps will run fastest there.

If you want a less biased benchmark, take a look at http://www2.webkit.org/perf/sunspider-0.9/sunspider.html - although Chrome does best there as well.

Comment: @http://www.google.com/support/orkut/bin/answer.py?hl=en-US&answer=182236 in right column google claims "Orkut runs faster in Chrome"

Answer (score 0):

> Is it true?

No.

The websites are based on standards, like HTML and Javascript. The actual site served up by Google is more or less the same for each browser. There may be some conditional code per-browser that makes the site "work" for that browser, but otherwise the site is the same for each browser. This means that the sites will work the fastest on the browser with the fastest rendering and Javascript Engine. At the moment I believe Opera is leading the way, so the sites will run faster in Opera.

Comment: ok . I heard somewhere gmailk will work faster in chrome than firefox and IE.

Comment: The websites are based on standards, like HTML and Javascript. The actual site served up by Google is more or less the same for each browser. There may be some conditional code per-browser that makes the site "work" for that browser, but otherwise the site is the same for each browser. This means that the sites will work the fastest on the browser with the fastest rendering and Javascript Engine. At the moment I believe Opera is leading the way, so the sites will run faster in Opera.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, but:

1. the speed increase will be unnoticeable most if the time
2. Google's developers don't deliberately write it that way, so don't worry :)

The fastest rendering and JavaScript engines lie in either Google Chrome or Opera at this point, but all browsers perform about the same in real life usage, except for IE, which is horribly slow (and not very accurate with standards).